# How to find purchased history from AppStore on Catalina OS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mac-appstore

In previous versions in AppStore was a tab like "Purchased", but after update I don't see this tab...

Issue is that I paid for the app from AppStore, but after I reinstalled the OS, I wan't to get this application again because I have already paid for this, but in AppStore I don't have button `get` I can't see the button with price written on it... Like I need to pay again...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try sign out and into the app store.. The title says, you need purchase history, but are you sure it would fix the app asking money again ? Please [edit] to remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the lower left hand corner of the **App Store** window, click the **Sign In** button.

Once signed in, click on your name in the lower left hand corner of the **App Store** window, as shown by the red arrow in the image below.

[image]